# What Swing layout(s) should I use for this?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

Could someone please tell me what Layouts I should use to make it look like the image below? I know that you'll have to use multiple layouts for this, but what I'm having the most problem is I don't know what my main panel layout will be, the panel that will containing other panels inside.

Please I just neeed to know what panel layouts I should use to make it look like the picture below. (The frame stretches and some of the buttons also stretches)

[image: Layout]

Comment: I'd have to write the code before I could tell you which Swing layouts to use.  Study the Oracle [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`GridBagLayout` is a very flexible layout, and you can use it to accomplish the example shown.

Oracle has a great tutorial on how to use `GridBagLayout`. It should be easy to find on Google.

Comment: That said, it might be easiest to understand if you break the problem down to three-to-five small layouts nested in a larger layout.

Answer (score 1):

Rarely would you use a single layout manager.

For example to display the button number 1-7 you might do something like:

```
JPanel left = new JPanel( new GridLayout(2, 0) ); // 2 rows
left.add( new JButton("1") );
left.add( new JButton("2") );

JPanel center = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
center.add(new JButton("3"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
center.add(new JButton("4"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
center.add(new JButton("5"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

JPanel right = new JPanel( new GridLayout(2, 0) ); // 2 rows
right.add( new JButton("5") );
right.add( new JButton("6") );

JPanel buttons = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 3) ); // 3 columns
buttons.add(left);
buttons.add(center);
buttons.add(right);
```

For the "Help", "Advanced", "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons you might want to use a horizontal BoxLayout. You can use horizontal glue and a horizontal strut as required to get the dynamic and fixed spacing between the buttons.

I'll let you figure out how to group other components into logical panels and then choose an appropriate layout manager for the panel.

Check out the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples of each layout manager.